# ASPX Page <%:Page.Title %> vs. <%=Page.Title %>

Tags: asp.net

Could someone explain what is the difference between ASPX Page <%:Page.Title %> and  <%=Page.Title %> when written as part of ASP.NET aspx file?

Comment: I never saw the first syntax <%: it make me think to a Razor one. Did you try both of these yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%:` is the same as `<%=`, except it auto-html-encodes the value withing the tag.